# Search command using vb6

Tags: vb6

How can I search a record from Ms access By only entering the BookID, using vb6?
example, I want to search a record, I will just enter the Book_ID and all the records that is inside that BookID will appear..
the command for deleting is : sql = "DELETE FROM c Where Book_ID=" + Text1
but what about in searching?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: Replace DELETE with SELECT

Answer (score 0):

sql="select * from c where Book_ID=" + Text1.Text